# Choose PDF or image files from Google Drive intent

Tags: android, android-intent, google-drive-api

I can create an intent which enables choosing an image file, but it doesn't let me select a PDF:

```
private void showFileChooser() {
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture PDF      "), PICK_PDF_REQUEST);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == PICK_PDF_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
        filePath = data.getData();
    }
}
```

The explicit intent:

```
 private void uploadFile() {
    //if there is a file to upload
    if (filePath != null) {
        //displaying a progress dialog while upload is going on

        Uri pdfUri = Uri.parse(String.valueOf(filePath));
        Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(this)
                .setText("Share PDF doc")
                .setType("image/*|application/pdf|audio/*")
                .setStream(pdfUri)
                .getIntent()
                .setPackage("com.google.android.apps.docs");
        startActivity(shareIntent);
    }
    //if there is not any file
    else {
        //you can display an error toast
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FileProvider.getUriForFile` -

```
Uri pdfUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, FILES_AUTHORITY, filePath);
Intent shareIntent = ShareCompat.IntentBuilder.from(activity)
.setStream(pdfUri)
.getIntent();

shareIntent.setData(pdfUri);
shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

Also add provider in manifest -

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="<your provider authority>"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
  <meta-data
      android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
      android:resource="@xml/file_provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

Also -

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path name="shared" path="shared/"/>
</paths>
```